# How to make a class override an element CSS style?

Tags: html, css

Below is my CSS and HTML code respectively. I want all paragraphs to be black font except for one group of three. I know that I could give each of these three paragraphs their own class but I would prefer if there was a way to change all of them at once. I thought that wrapping them in a div tag and giving that div tag the ".special-paragraphs" class would work but it doesn't. Is there any way to do this or am I forced to edit each paragraph individually?

```
p { 
  color: black; 
}

.special-paragraphs {
  color: chartreuse;
  background-color: pink;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

---

```
  <div class="special-paragraphs">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. <br>
      Quo, quaerat repudiandae ad culpa minus repellat dolore, possimus <br>
      nemo qui sunt voluptas architecto iure accusantium nihil pariatur <br>
      dolores debitis error asperiores.</p>
    <p>Amet perspiciatis, cupiditate illo pariatur rem quasi ab <br>
      reprehenderit? Ex nisi consectetur possimus, corrupti voluptates <br>
      ullam, quod accusamus id iure quas consequuntur? Obcaecati aspernatur <br>
      minima, temporibus ea sed totam adipisci!</p>
    <p>Ipsa odit aut dicta perspiciatis vero commodi sequi reiciendis. <br>
      Eum fugit sapiente blanditiis non quisquam veniam harum iusto! Ex, <br>
      at. Laboriosam iusto provident consequuntur ab necessitatibus deserunt <br>
      ducimus, fugit fuga!</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
<p style="color:black">
```

...it's not the better, but works

Comment: This is exactly what my question is trying to work around. And the color of the paragraphs are black and I'm trying to make them chartreuse in this case.

Answer (score 0):

try add !important :

```
    .special-paragraphs {
      color: chartreuse !important;
      background-color: pink;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to give the style for default P element. Because it will overwrite all the P elements. So you have to add the style for special-paragraphs only. It will work.

```
.special-paragraphs
{
  color: chartreuse;
  background-color: pink;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```
<p>I am normal</p>
<div class="special-paragraphs">
<p>I am red</p>
<p>I am blue</p>
<p>I am green</p>
<div>
```

Comment: What if I want to make every paragraph blue except for a cluster of three? Then I make all paragraphs blue in CSS and then I try to make just the three chartreuse using a div tag but it won't work.